# Where I can use + and > in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

This may be a basic question but to me it is still confusing where I can use `+` or `>` in CSS.

I see many selectors like `li > a` or `div + span` etc. but I am not sure what the difference is and when to use them?

Comment: [Read the manual, please.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching) - `E > F` : [Child Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors). Matches any F element that is a (direct) child of an element E. - `E + F` : [Adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors). Matches any F element immediately preceded by a sibling element E. [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

Comment: [this](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/css2/) can help

Comment: @bažmegakapa how could he google it if he doesn't know what '+' or '>' is called as?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The **>** sign means select a direct descendant

Example:

**CSS**

```
div > ul {
   list-style: none;
}
```

**HTML**
Here the style would apply to the `<ul>`

```
<div>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The **+** sign means select an adjacent sibling

Example:

**CSS**

```
p + p
{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

**HTML**
Here the style would apply to the latter `<p>`

```
<div>
   <p></p>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I would thanks to all of you. with this answer have one confusion. for eg. li > a means it will affect immidiate child. so will it affect any sub child a tag too? for +  what is the difference by using + than grouping class?

Comment: It will only affect the immediate <a> not any subchildren. The only difference is that the + will affect only adjacent siblings. Where a grouping class would affect everything that has that class applied.

Comment: and what about + .. ? I mean I am still confuse between grouping class and using + ... is there any specific use of + or both are the same.

Comment: I have checked with subchild by using > and it is affecting to them too.. so why with me if you are saying it should affect only first child and not sub child of first child???

Answer (score 6):

The selectors are extensively explained in the [W3 CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors), but here is a digest:

**Immediate child selector**

The `>` selector is the [immediate child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors). In your example `li > a`, the rule would select any `<a>` element that is an immediate child of an `<li>` element.

The rule would select the anchor in this example:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">An anchor</a></li>
</ul>
```

**The adjacent sibling selector**

The `+` selector is the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors). In your example `div + span`, the rule would select any `<span>` elements that is immediately preceded by a `<div>` element, and where they both share the same parent.

The span element would be selected in this case:

```
<article>
   <div>A preceding div element</div>
   <span>This span would be selected</span>
</article>
```

Comment: "div + span selects the span if it has the same parent as div." Ah ok, so the `div` doesn't need to come _before_ the `span`? Would it match both `span`s in this HTML? `<span/><div/><span/>`. I thought only the second `span` would match here.

Comment: From the spec you linked to (emphasis added): Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: E1 + E2, where E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if E1 and E2 share the same parent in the document tree **and E1 immediately precedes E2**, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments).

Answer (score 2):

The `>` is the **direct child** selector. In your example of `li > a`, this will only select `<a>` tags that are *direct* descendants of the `<li>`.

The `+` means siblings of the selected elements. In your example, `div + span` would select any `<span>`s next to a `<div>` (with the same parent).

Answer (score 0):

`li > a` would only select `a` elements that are direct descendants of `li` elements. `div + span` would only select `span` elements that follow a `div` element.

Read more in @bažmegakapa's link: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the + sign but the > sign in css means direct child of, consider this

```
div > h1 { color: red; }
```

This will style all h1 tags that are a direct child of a div.

```
<h1>BLAH</h1>
<div>
    <h1>BLAH</h1>
</div>
```

In that case the first h1 would be left alone, the second because it is a direct child of the div tag would be red.